Matplotlib cannot plot function created with lamdify
I am trying to plot a function created from a string with implemented_function and lambdify. The function works for calculating single values, but not for plotting. I get an error, which states "Cannot convert expression to float" in the line of ax.plot(...).
Apparently sympy and matplotlib have some conflict. The full error message is printed below.
Does anyone know how to fix this?
Code:
import sympy as sympy
from sympy import lambdify, Function, Lambda
from sympy.abc import x, y, z
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import implemented_function
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.show()
inf = implemented_function(Function('f'), lambda x: eval("x"))
f = lambdify(x, inf(x))
ax.plot(x, f(x), color="blue", linestyle=":", label = "f(x)")

Error Message:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[27], line 25
     23 inf = implemented_function(Function('f'), lambda x: eval("x"))
     24 f = lambdify(x, inf(x))
---> 25 ax.plot(x, f(x), color="blue", linestyle=":", label = "f(x)")

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py:1781, in Axes.plot(self, scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1779 lines = [*self._get_lines(self, *args, data=data, **kwargs)]
   1780 for line in lines:
-> 1781     self.add_line(line)
   1782 if scalex:
   1783     self._request_autoscale_view("x")

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py:2339, in _AxesBase.add_line(self, line)
   2336 if line.get_clip_path() is None:
   2337     line.set_clip_path(self.patch)
-> 2339 self._update_line_limits(line)
   2340 if not line.get_label():
   2341     line.set_label(f'_child{len(self._children)}')

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py:2362, in _AxesBase._update_line_limits(self, line)
   2358 def _update_line_limits(self, line):
   2359     """
   2360     Figures out the data limit of the given line, updating self.dataLim.
   2361     """
-> 2362     path = line.get_path()
   2363     if path.vertices.size == 0:
   2364         return

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py:1037, in Line2D.get_path(self)
   1035 """Return the `~matplotlib.path.Path` associated with this line."""
   1036 if self._invalidy or self._invalidx:
-> 1037     self.recache()
   1038 return self._path

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py:674, in Line2D.recache(self, always)
    672 if always or self._invalidx:
    673     xconv = self.convert_xunits(self._xorig)
--> 674     x = _to_unmasked_float_array(xconv).ravel()
    675 else:
    676     x = self._x

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook.py:1398, in _to_unmasked_float_array(x)
   1396     return np.ma.asarray(x, float).filled(np.nan)
   1397 else:
-> 1398     return np.asarray(x, float)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sympy\core\expr.py:340, in Expr.__float__(self)
    338 if result.is_number and result.as_real_imag()[1]:
    339     raise TypeError("Cannot convert complex to float")
--> 340 raise TypeError("Cannot convert expression to float")

TypeError: Cannot convert expression to float


You are calling matplotlib's plot with a symbol x as first argument.  Matplotlib needs a float, a list (or array) of floats to plot.  E.g. with import numpy as np: xs = np.linspace(-5,5,1000) and then ax.plot(xs, f(xs), ....).

See also e.g. Lambdify not working inside function

If I read the error stack correctly, it's trying to make a numpy array (or float) from the first plot argument, your x.  But that is a sympy expression, a symbol.  It didn't even get so far as use the lambdified function.  There's nothing like this usage in the matplotlib documentation.

Did you try sympy's own plot interface? sympy.plot(inf(x))

Perhaps the biggest clue is in the final Exception message

TypeError: Cannot convert expression to float

As described in the comments, matplotlib's ax.plot() is expecting a value or collection of values, not just a callable which could be used to produce them (it doesn't know or offer to guess how many or which range of values it should show)!
Instead, either call your function (lambda) on a collection of values and pass that new, resulting collection of values to .plot() .. or consider directly using SymPy's builtin plotting logic (wraps matplotlib), which can handle displaying indefinite expressions and may be what you intended (in which case you don't need to create the lambda and can directly use SymPy expressions)
evaluating a collection of points
import numpy as np
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
inf = implemented_function(Function('f'), lambda x: eval("x"))
f = lambdify(x, inf(x))
xs = np.linspace(-10,10,1000)  # generate points [-10,10] chosen to match sympy defaults
ax.plot(xs, f(xs), color="blue", linestyle=":", label = "f(x)")
plt.show()  # later and optional in some environments

Also as noted in the comments, it may cause confusion re-using the name x in several namespaces - specifically when given as an argument to the lambda, x is a new name, and not the x of the outer scope

SymPy builtin
sympy.plot(inf(x))  # NOTE sympy.plot(x) is sufficient here!


